# javascripts added to page

Tags: javascript, html

in my html page I do not have any external js file but when I load page in console lots of js scripts are loaded !

[image]

and this's html code of page :

```
<html>
<header>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>سامانه مدیریت تلفن همراه</title>

    <link href="<?php echo  style_url ?>/css/stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style media="screen">

    @font-face {
      font-family: yekan;
      src: url(<?php echo  style_url ?>/fonts/yekan.ttf);
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: ronald;
      src: url(<?php echo  style_url ?>/fonts/ronald.ttf);
    }
    </style>



</header>
<body style="font-family:yekan">
    <div id="loader"><img src="<?php echo  style_url ?>/img/loader.gif" /></div>
<?php
$login=new login('default');
if ($login::check())
{
?>
    <div class="wrapper">

<?php require "sidebar.view.php" ; } ?>
<div class="dialog" id="source" style="display: none;" title="Source"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is sidebar page content which included in page :

```
<div class="sidebar" >

    <div class="top">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"></a>
            <!--div class="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search..."/>
                </div>
            </div-->
        </div>
        <div class="nContainer">
            <ul class="navigation bordered">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="blblue">مدیریت</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="blpurple">همگام سازی</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="blyellow">گزینه ها</a>
                    <div class="open"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ui.html">UI Elements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="grid_sys.html">Grid System</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="blgreen">مالی</a>
                    <div class="open"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="forms.html">افزودن اعتبار </a></li>
                        <li><a href="validation.html">تراکنش ها</a></li>
                        <li><a href="grid.html">تعرفه ها</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="statistic.html" class="blred">Statistic</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="bldblue">Tables</a>
                    <div class="open"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="tables.html">Simple</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tables_dynamic.html">Dynamic</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <a href="#" class="blpurple">Samples</a>
                    <div class="open"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailbox.html">Mailbox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a></li>
                        <li><a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="blorange">کاربری</a>
                    <div class="open"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="files.html">تغییر گذر واژه</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#logout" onclick="logout()">خروج</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="close">
                <span class="ico-remove"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="widget" dir="rtl" style="color:white">

        </div>

</div>
<form method="post" id="logout_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="function" value="<?php echo core::encrypt('logout',0) ?>" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function logout()
  {
    $("#logout_form").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not even Google Analytics? Anyway... as we can't see your HTML code, I can't tell you anything more.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you have ads on your page?

Comment: No ads , No google Analytic codes! completely i mixed up
I will add my html code just a moment

Comment: From the domain name in the XHR request, I'd say your server's been compromised.

Comment: And what's in `sidebar.view.php`, since you're including it: `<?php require "sidebar.view.php" ; } ?>` ?

Comment: that's localhost in windows 7 with easyphp 5.4.6

Comment: @Farhad: Doesn't mean it's not compromised. But again: You haven't shown the content that will make up the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added sidebar content

Comment: @Farhad: The sidebar uses a `$` function you don't define anywhere. That usually means you're including jQuery somewhere (could be Prototype or MooTools or anything else, really). So where's *that* include?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I deleted that sidebar but again I have the same result !

Comment: I've added a community wiki answer listing the possibilities. In the end, this isn't an appropriate question for SO, because it boils down to debugging things we can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really only four options here:

1. You *do* have a script on your page that you're just missing. (There isn't any in your question except the code that seems to use jQuery even though jQuery isn't loaded — so that suggests what's shown is not the complete story.)
2. You have a browser extension/add-on (or compromise) which is adding these scripts to the page. (Whether you *intentionally* installed it, or it was installed by malware [and I include bundles like the Ask Toolbar bundled with Java installations and similar — e.g., installing something completely unrelated unless you untick a subtle tickbox if there even is one — in the term "malware").)
3. Your server has been compromised and the scripts are being injected by malware. (Yes, this is entirely possible even if it's your local computer. In fact, it's probably *more* likely.)
4. It's observation error and the scripts aren't really there.

We can't help you in most of those scenarios.

Comment: In both Firefox and chrome I had same result and I don not have extensions so i do not think number two could happen but i upload it to my C panel host to see the result , thanks for your help

Comment: problem is related to my own browser I saw that codes in stack overflow consoles too :)

Answer (score -1):

these script are loading from a different source online...if there are other links such css file....ensure to check if there are any external links in the css file..

Solution

1.remove all css links, 
2.run the page and inspect elements to view if the scripts are still loading
if the are not the external links are in your css files else the code of your page properly the javascript file link might be withing the body of the page...